# Is there a hardware wallet project that plans to add multisig capabilities?

Tags: wallet, multi-signature, wallet-security, hardware-wallet

What I want: A hardware wallet that I don't need to trust.

That wallet will hold one out of three keys in a 2-of-3 multisig scheme. The other two parties will be a paper wallet I create, and a password that I choose.

Now, I can store the paper wallet in a safe, and use the hardware wallet + password in my day to day life. If I forget the password, I can recover using hardware + paper. If I lose the wallet, I can recover using paper + password (paper is stored in multiple bank vaults).

**At any point in this process, an evil hardware wallet maker cannot steal my bitcoins.**

Do any of the hardware wallet projects plan to support such a scheme?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you want, but it's close:

The [Case hardware wallet](https://choosecase.com/) uses 2-of-3 multisig, where one key is on the device, one is on Case servers, and the third recovery key has two options: Self-storage or Vault storage through [Third Key Solutions](https://www.thirdkey.solutions/) (invisible to the customer). If you choose the self-storage option, you provide an `xpub` key during initial setup, and the multisig wallet will use that as the third key.

In that scheme you would have signing control of 2 of the 3 keys. There is still the human trust element where Case servers are necessary to perform the transactions, but they cannot sign any transactions not initiated by the user.

Full disclosure: I work at Case.

Comment: As I mentioned, I work at Case. I tried to word this as non-advertisey as possible, please let me know if I should make any edits.